# Jquery scrollX and and scrollY are not showing up properly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with Jquery datatables. I want to add horizontal and vertical scroll bars to the Data Table.So I have added the following code:

```
//DataTables aplies style and behavior to <table>
    var table = $('#test').DataTable({
        "scrollY": 315, // inconsistent IE7/other
        "scrollX": true,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false
    });
```

For some reason, the Data Table scroll bars are not showing up/not working properly in IE11. But the same scroll bars are displayed properly in chrome and firefox.

The following is the screenshot in IE11(I have highlighted the issue in the pic):

[image]

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the root cause for the issue. Some how the datatable is been disabled by some part of the code.Correcting the code fixed the issue.